# knockout js Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option.

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In my js i am calling a function on click here is my function

```
 function PopulateBranch(branchAreaName) {

    var nodePath = "/content/eng/phone-numbers/jcr:content/content-page/wireframe";

    $.ajax({
        data:  "action="+"getBranch"+  "&nodePath=" + nodePath +  "&nodeName=" + branchAreaName,
        url: '/bin/branchlocator/crud' , 
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {

            self.PopulateBranch = ko.computed(function(){
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
                    branchView.Branches.push(new Branch(item));
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });

};
```

i am calling this function inside a view model but i am getting this error when i call this function

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.
```

any solution ??

Comment: What do you think `self.PopulateBranch = ko.computed(...)` does? Please provide more code (e.g. the definition of `branchView.Branches`, is the outer `PopulateBranch` a global function, how exactly you are calling `PopulateBranch`).

Comment: yes it is global function... iw ill try to provide more code to you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/43zkoszu/18/ here is fiddle link i am calling function on click of show branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function PopulateBranch(branchAreaName) { ... }` is a global function in your code. When you call it for the first time, this happens:

- You call `PopulateBranch("someAreaName")`.
- It makes an AJAX call.
- When the AJAX call succeeds, the success handler is called and executes the following code:  `self.PopulateBranch = ko.computed(...);`. You don't have a variable called `self` in scope, so it resolves to `window.self`, which equals `window`, also known as the global scope. That means that this line of code *replaces* the old `function PopulateBranch(branchAreaName) { ... }` with the new `ko.computed` handler.
- The next time you call `PopulateBranch("someAreaName")`, you are no longer calling the original `PopulateBranch()` function, you are calling the `ko.computed` version.

To fix your problem, you should remove that `self.PopulateBranch = ko.computed(...);` line and replace it with different code that updates your `Branches` array. Perhaps you just need this:

```
success: function(data) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item) {
        branchView.Branches.push(new Branch(item));
    });
}
```

By the way, I think you are misunderstanding the use of `ko.computed`. The `BranchAreaViewModel`'s `PopulateBranches` should not be a `ko.computed` either, it can be an ordinary function. `ko.computed` should be used when you want to compute a value based on another observable value, for example, if you have an observable tracking elapsed time in seconds, you can use a `ko.computed` to compute a string representation of that elapsed time, knockout will automatically recalculate that string whenever the observable value changes.

Comment: but now whenever i am clicking showFields it is adding fields in it . first time it is 2 then its 4 then its 6

Comment: That's what `push` does to an array... If you want to remove the old contents of the array, do `Branches.removeAll()` before `push`ing new data into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905527/validation-not-working-in-knockout-js/25905592#25905592  here is another question 4 u